# Scala List toString()

Tags: list, scala

I have a `List[List[]]`

```
List(List(1,2), List(3,4))
```

If I call `toString()` on it

`List(List(1,2), List(3,4)).toString()`

Is it possible to restore back the original `List[List[]]` if yes, How?

Thanks.

Comment: i wont rely on converting a toString output into the object. what if the toString implementation changes? Why do you have such a requirement and can you perhaps use any other means to serialize information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, as in Java (and even Python, though libraries usually keep to convention), there's no guarantee that a `.toString` will produce a something that, compiled, will re-create the object. In fact, common types such as `Long` and `String` do not produce a string output that can be used to recreate them.

Note that the standard way of producing output that can be used to recreate instances is through *serialization*. If that's what you want, look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to parse the string you get from `toString`? If so there's no native way to do this (like Python's `eval` or Haskell's `read`, for example), but you can pretty easily roll your own with the [Scala parser combinator library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/RegexParsers.html):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._    

object parseIntListList extends RegexParsers {
  def list = "List(" ~> repsep("\\d+".r ^^ (_.toInt), ",") <~ ")"
  def apply(s: String) = parse("List(" ~> repsep(list, ",") <~ ")", s)
}
```

Now `parseIntListList(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)).toString)` does what you want, and the parser is robust against extra whitespace, etc.

There's almost certainly a better way to do whatever you're trying to do in Scala, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know it is a List of List of Int?

```
val li = List(List(1,2), List(3,4))
val s = li.toString 

s.replaceAll ("[^0-9) ]", "").split ("\\)").map(_.split (" ").filterNot (_.equals ("")).map (_.toInt).toList).toList
res86: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
```